# Non-Blocking File Reads

Tags: java, c++, io, java-native-interface

Is there a non-blocking file read API in java? If not would it be wise to build one in C++ and call it from a java app via JNI?

Comment: What do you want to use it for?

Comment: What is wrong with using a blocking model?

Comment: Potential IO blocks would interfere with the MDB's lifecycle.

Comment: can you expand on that?  how would that interfere?

Comment: I assume MDB stands for Message Driven Bean, not the MS Access file format?

Comment: @finnw yes, MDB for Message Driven Bean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `FileChannel` does not extend `SelectableChannel`.

Probably because not all OSes support it.

Windows does, and in theory you could write a windows-specific C++ library and call it via JNI, but it is a lot of work to integrate this with `java.nio`.

I would rather have a worker thread copy the file contents to a [pipe](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Pipe.html) and do non-blocking reads on the other end of the pipe.

Answer (score 23):

My original answer is now wrong, since the addition of [`AsynchronousFileChannel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html) in Java 7.

You still cannot [select](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#select%28%29) on a file, but there are now two asynchronous file read methods: one that takes a [callback](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html#read%28java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20long,%20A,%20java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler%29) and [another](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html#read%28java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20long%29) that returns a [`Future`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

It may be cleaner to use the callback method (and dispatch an event from the callback) than to have a dedicated thread polling a pipe.

Comment: Asychronous is not the same as non-blocking though. In fact asynchronous IO operations [use a mandatory thread pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousChannelGroup.html) where as non-blocking IO obviously doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

`AsynchronousFileChannel` is the right answer. Yet, it does not provide an easy API. It is quite verbose to use it comparing with the similar usage of `java.nio.file.Files` that provides simple static methods, such as: `readAllLines` or `lines`. Unfortunately `Files` methods are synchronous.

The `AsyncFiles` alternative from [RxIo](https://github.com/javasync/RxIo) provides the corresponding non-blocking methods, with 3 different APIs: callback based, `CompletableFuture` and also with *reactive streams*. Here it is an example with *reactive streams*:

```
AsyncFiles
    .lines(path)
    .subscribe(doOnNext(line -> /*... use line from background thread ...*/));
```